# Let $R$ be a ring with unity. Consider $X^2 - 1$ $\in$ $R[X]$. Then $X^2 - 1$ has at most two roots in R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Indicate True/False

Let $R$ be a ring with unity. Consider $X^2 - 1$   $\in$  $R[X]$. Then $X^2 - 1$
has at most two roots in R.

I need a hint to solve this problem.

I have tried some common rings to come up with counter examples but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different answer that is, in some way, very discoverable and scalable.

Let $F$ be a field not of characteristic 2. Then in $F^n$ (the product of n copies of $F$), every element with entries only from $\{1,-1\}$ satisfies $a^2=1$, and would be a root of $X^2-1$.

This is quite different from the integers mod 8 since that ring is indecomposable, and this ring has no nilpotent elements besides $0$.

Comment: this request is not pertaining to this particular question, I am an undergrad student preparing for graduate exams, regular textbooks do give a good exposure to theory but i am unable to find a good problem book in ring theory, since your field of specialization is ring theory could you pls help out ..thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** If $m$ is odd then 
$$m^2-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer ..but could you elaborate on how you approached the problem..